# Is it possible to write Tower Defense in C/SDL

Tags: c, sdl

I have to write Tower Defense game in ANSI C using SDL library, but the deeper I go into LazyFoo's tutorial, the more I got this feeling that's impossible to write it in pure C due to limitations. So my questions is - am I in big trouble or I'm just panicking. It has to be a simple tower defense game, nothing fancy, but is it possible to do it using only C?

Comment: What are these limitations you speak of?

Comment: If in doubt, you can embed assembly code in C.  So any compiled code written in any language can be embedded as assembly code into C code.  Granted, that's probably not practical...

Comment: The original Rollercoaster Tycoon was written in 99% assembly language! (Count yourself lucky!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C is a Turing-complete language so anything you can do in some other language can be done in C, too. And SDL provides you with a graphics API which is commonly used for (usually small/indie) games.

Of course it might be more pleasant to write it e.g. in C++ or a higher-level language such as C# or Python - but it's possible in C nonetheless.

TL;DR: **Yes, it is totally possible.**

Comment: I know using C++ or C# would be so much easier, but unfortunately I have to do it in C and only C. Anyhow, I'd better get to it.

Comment: Nope. That's why I added the sentence about having a graphics API available later.

Comment: @Oren I'm going to do that just to prove myself right.

Comment: @H2CO3 good luck with that. I'd be the first to congratulate you if I'm wrong :)